# kivy - issues with canvas coordinate system (global vs. local)

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

With a section of my kv-file as shown below, I want to draw lines onto the canvas of ShowRectangle.

However, I run into the following problem.

The widget "ParentOfShowRectangle" provides the upper 85% of a BoxLayout to "ShowRectangle", the lower 15% to some buttons.

The Scatter of "ShowRectangle" is rendered properly to the upper 85%. However, the Lines in canvas.after are not drawn within the upper 85% of the screen, but intersect the lower 15% (the buttons).  Even so, they have correct length, etc. (scaling with their 85% portion).

It seems, weather it just misses a proper offset of the coordinate system by 15%.
Might this be a problem with a wrongly chosen coordinate system?
I cannot figure out the reason.

ShowRectangle inherits from BoxLayout.
ParentOfShowRectangle inherits from Screen.

---

The kv-file

```
<ShowRectangle>:
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            width: 3
            points: self.size[0] * 0.05, self.size[1] * 0.05, self.size[0] * 0.05, self.size[1] * 0.95, self.size[0] * 0.95, self.size[1] * 0.95, self.size[0] * 0.95, self.size[1] * 0.05
            close: True
    Scatter:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        size_hint: 1, 1

<ParentOfShowRectangle>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ShowRectangle:
            size_hint: 1, 0.85
            size: 1, 0.85
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.15
            height: 1, 0.15
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel.'
                font_size: root.button_font_size
                size_hint: 1, 0.6
                height: ...
            Button:
                text: 'Ok.'
                font_size: root.button_font_size
                size_hint: 1, 0.6
                height: ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to use self.center for the relative positioning:

```
self.center[0]-self.size[0] * 0.45, self.center[1]-self.size[1] * 0.45, \
self.center[0]+self.size[0] * 0.45, self.center[1]-self.size[1] * 0.45, \
self.center[0]+self.size[0] * 0.45, self.center[1]+self.size[1] * 0.45, \
self.center[0]-self.size[0] * 0.45, self.center[1]+self.size[1] * 0.45
```